# silver badge tenacious

Tags: support, badges

I was browsing through the list of silver badges. And I came across a few explanations to which are not that easy to understand. For example,

Silver badge : TENACIOUS.

It says:

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

I didn't get it. What is it exactly?

Many other explanations are not that obvious too. They need to be more explained, I guess. I hope I am at the right platform asking the right question.

Comment: See also: [Better description of “Tenacious Badge”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69322/1438) and [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/1438). The tenacious badge is particularly strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you post all of the ones that need an explanation, I will expand this answer.

That description you posted means that your answers that were accepted yet have a zero score (no votes, or upvotes and downvotes cancel out) represent 20% of your total answers. There must be more than 5 of these to get the badge.

Does that make sense?

Comment: ya it does. point made. :)
To post all those, i will sit one day and give the list. Thank you.